# Task Manager and Process Lasso close unexpectedly after a few minutes

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I've had this issue for a while, where the Task Manager will just close by itself after being open for a few minutes. I first thought it was a virus, but honestly, that's a poorly written virus if it waits to close the Task Manager. But I did my due diligence and full scanned my computer. I now have it scanning every night with no issues. Then I recently installed Process Lasso and it has a GUI similar to Task Manager and it does the same thing. I use Panda Dome as antivirus, so I put the Process Lasso exe's in the exclude list but it still happens.

Not sure what is going on here, anyone have any suggestions?

Windows 10 Pro
V1909
Build 18363.1016

UPDATE:
Well I talked to a Microsoft agent and turns out I needed to upgrade form V1909 to V2004. So far so good.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 Pro?  Task Manager closing / locking up was a problem up to about V1903.  My recall is it was working in V1909 and certainly works fine in V2004 and beyond (Windows Insider).

Comment: V1909
Build 18363.1016

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW.  Restart and test. You could try a controlled boot (MSCONFIG) to see if there is a conflicting app.  That takes a bit of time.

Comment: Is there anything in the application event log to suggest that the process crashes?

Comment: Did the SFC and it repaired something. Ran it again to make sure there wasn't more, nothing. Restarted and sure enough Task Manager closed after 13 minutes. I looked in the applicaton event logs and nothing comes up.

Comment: Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.900

Image Version: 10.0.18363.1016

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\Windows\system32> SFC /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Well the only correlation that I see in the Event Viewer is the Security Audit that happens right when this process shuts down.